# Postfix on fedora 20 not receiving mail

Tags: postfix, fedora-20

I am running fedora 20 with postfix. It can send mail fine, but does not log anything and cannot receive emails. The packets are reaching the computer fine as I can see them come in when I monitor port 25 with tcpdump, but /var/log/mail.log does not exist, and no mail is deposited in either /var/mail/username or /var/spool/mail/unsername. I've checked selinux booleans, and they are enabled, properly. I'm at my wits end with this. here is the output of my postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = dev.domain.com
myhostname = dev.domain.com
mynetworks_style = class
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: Are you logging at all? Fedora does not install a system logger by default.

Comment: what should I use? syslog? do I have to re-install postfix?

Comment: I use `rsyslog`, as I expect most people do.

Comment: I'm new to fedora. Thanks. Is there anything in my output that would break mail delivery?

Comment: Try to find out where postfix put its log. The log is valuable assets for troubleshooting your present problem and the future one.

Comment: How does postfix register with syslog? my system created a maillog file that remains empty.

Comment: it logs only for outgoing mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem with postfix. It seems you don't have logger installed. Try rsyslogd or syslog-ng.

Comment: Installed rsyslog, re-installed and restarted postfix. maillog folder was created, it remains empty.

Comment: *maillog file was created

Comment: Logging correctly now, but still doesn't receive mail from the network, only from localhost. Firewall issue?

Comment: firewall was blocking port 25. Works fine now, thanks.